# Why Glassfish Server 4.1 is not Installing in Eclipse (Luna x86)?

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, internal

I have a problem installing/configuring  Glassfish Server 4.1 in Eclipse Luna x86 in windows 8. I m working with Java EE 7, and for my projects I need Glassfish Server 4.1, but eclipse shows me the following error:

[Image error in GlassFish - Eclipse Luna](http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/141003022815506680.jpg)

How can I solve this error?

I need it for testing my Java EE 7 application.

Comment: I have windows 7 I get "The specified directory is not a valid GlassFish installation". I think it is because the eclipse changes "\" to "/".

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I solved it by installing GlassFish Tool available from:

https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/spotlight_on_glassfish_4_19

... just follow that article and be aware that the UI uses the generic 'GlassFish 4' version, which encompass 4.1 as well!
After restart of your IDE it should work's fine.